# js: can I assign a class or an id to an html-element that's part of a variable definition?

Tags: javascript, html

NOTE: My knowledge of programming is scant.

---

I've got this line of code somewhere:

```
var item = "<h3>" + '<a href="' + postUrl + '" target="_blank">' + postTitle + "</a> </h3> <p>" + postContent + "</p>";
```

`postUrl` , `postTitle` and `PostContent` have previously been declared.

I'd like to wrap it all up inside a `<div>` tag that has some class or id assigned to it, as in...

```
var item = "<div id="special"> <h3>" + '<a href="' + postUrl + '" target="_blank">' + postTitle + "</a> </h3> <p>" + postContent + "</p> </div>";
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Is it because of the quotations getting messed up or is it the wrong way to go altogether?

Comment: It's because you're trying to use double-quote `"` characters inside a string delimited by double-quote `"` characters; that won't ever work unless you escape the characters, like so: `\"` or simply delimit the strings with single-quote `'`characters. I would, however, suggest using the DOM, rather than string concatenation, to create the HTML elements.

Comment: `var item = '<div id="special"> <h3>' + '<a href="' + postUrl + '" target="_blank">' + postTitle + "</a> </h3> <p>" + postContent + "</p> </div>";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Escaping the `"` quotes inside your string literal, like this: `"<div id=\"special\"> <h3>"`
2. Or using single quotes `'` for either the outer string or inner one *(you have the choice)*, like this: `'<div id="special"> <h3>'` or `"<div id='special'> <h3>"`

I personally prefer `'<div id="special"> <h3>'` because the generated `HTML` will contain the `"` quotes (which is the HTML standard) while keeping the `JavaScript` more readable and maintainable (compared to using escaped quotes)